# How can I find how many times, and where, a function has been called in a PHP application?

Tags: php

I have a large PHP application that has been maintained by multiple teams for over a decade, and as such, the app has been through several update iterations as PHP has evolved over the years.

I know I can call get_defined_functions() which will give me a list of all internal php functions as well as user defined functions, which is very helpful.

The problem is I don't know how to see how often, or where, each function is being used.

Ultimately, I would like to have a function that works like get_defined_functions but goes a step farther in not only showing the defined function but also showing how many times it has been used as well as in what file I can find it. (The search needs to be application wide, meaning I point it at the top level directory and it finds each occurrence through the 1000s of files that make up the application.)

How can I do this? Just want to make sure a solution doesn't already exist, either programmatically or through a tool, before I dive into writing a lot of complicated code to search through these files.

Comment: Use a proper IDE which would let you see all the references.

Comment: @Dharman do you have a recommendation? I'm currently using Netbeans 11 and can see a function list for the page I'm currently working in, but don't know how, or even if, I can see that application wide. I'm open to suggestions, so please recommend whatever ID and how to achieve that if you know of something for sure that could work. Thanks!

Comment: VSCode or PhpStorm

Comment: This sounds more like something for a profiller.  It works at run-time and can show many times a function is called etc.

Comment: Note that `get_defined_functions` will only know about functions a particular request is aware of. If you're using an autoloader or conditional includes (`if($foo) { include('functions.php'); }`), many possible functions won't be shown there.

Comment: @ceejayoz Good point, thanks for that. I don't know much about profilers as NigelRen suggested, but would they handle situations like that? Currently researching more about profilers, but seems like a solid direction to consider. Otherwise, I was going to loop through the get_defined_functions() results and then, for each one, search through each of the files for that name (which sounds convoluted, and I'm hoping to avoid having to do that).

Comment: Phpstorm can it ...

Comment: @user658182 Any IDE should have a "search in project" option that lets you search all the files in the project for a string. Easy enough to search the project for `name_of_my_function` and find all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something that records every function invocation and then analyze call statistics.

[Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) can do the first, yet it will slow down your application significantly, and then you can supply generated cachegring files to the [Webgring](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) or KCacheGrind to see what's going on.